# Show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not homeomorphic if $n\geq 2$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, connectedness

> Show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not homeomorphic if $n\geq 2$.

I want to use a connection-type argument. I thought of giving the following proof;

Suppose that there exist such a homemorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Then If I consider $\left.f \right|_{\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}}:\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}-\{f(0)\}$, $\left.f \right|_{\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}}$ is a restriction of $f$ and it is therefore a homeomorphism. However $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ is a connected space while $\mathbb{R}-\{f(0)\}$ is not which results in a contradiction since $\left.f \right|_{\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}}$ is a homeomorphism. Therefore such $f$ doesn't exist.

Is the restriction argument correct?

Comment: Looks almost okay, but don't use $f'$ and surely you meant $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n-\{f(0)\}$. :)

Answer (score 5):

Seems ok. But please don't use $f'$ for that restriction, it hurts (I thought of derivatives!). You can just say that $f\big|_{\Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\} }$ will be a homeomorphism between $\Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ and $\Bbb R \setminus\{f(0)\}$ and then proceed with the argument.

Comment: In topology using $f'$ for a related mapping which is not the derivative is perfectly fine in my opinion and also very common actually.

Answer (score 0):

That's the argument I too would give.